# How to maintain db pool connection

Tags: database, mongodb, threadpool, connection-pooling

I have questions about maintaining the db pool connection. Actually, I have client dbs which are used in multiple projects, so, for example, using Mongodb I have done something like
`Mongodb.connect(URL,{poolSize:5}, function(err,resp)=>{})`

. when a client hit an API this MongoDB connection is made, so now another client hit API it will again call mongo function again. Does poolSize concept working here ?? does two connections are made currently from poolSize or it something happen like this when i first hit

`Mongodb.connect(url,{poolSize:5}, function(err,resp)=>{this.connections[{'db':resp}})`

I stored connections in connections array now a client hit API a connection is made and the response is stored in an array and at the same time another client check if something exists in connections array, if it, it just uses that response to a query on db. How db connection pool working here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your app is *not* reusing a connection pool. The main issue is this part:

> when a client hit an API this MongoDB connection is made, so now
>   another client hit API it will again call mongo function again.

It sounds like a new `MongoDB` connection is created each time the API is called. Each of these calls will create their own distance connection pool. The `poolSize` will be enforced on each individual pool, but collectively the total number of connections can grow far beyond that limit.

The connections to the database should be made prior to the API being hit, such as on app startup. This would then allow the app to immediately use connections from the pool when the API is hit, rather than needing to wait for connections to opened.

This [blog post](https://blog.mlab.com/2017/05/mongodb-connection-pooling-for-express-applications/) provides some examples of the right and wrong ways to implement connection pooling, using Node.JS and Express as an example.